# Analog Sensor of 0 to 10 v connection to BeagleBone Black

Tags: analog, signal-processing, beaglebone-black, thermocouple

I have an analog sensor(Thermocouple) which provides an output voltage range of 0 to 10 volt. I want to connect it with a Beagle Bone Black. BBB accepts 0 to 1.8 volt as analog input. I thought of using a normal OPAMP buffer circuit (for impedance matching) followed by a voltage divider circuit with 82 Kohm and 18 Kohm as the two resistors where voltage across 18 Kohm will be considered as for further processing by BBB.
Is it a good idea? My application is that of heating where depending on feedback of the thermocouple, heating will be controlled.

Comment: As long a you're using kne op amp, may as well use two. I'd buffer before and after the divider to give the adc a nice low impedance input.

Comment: Can you tell us which thermocouple amplifier chip you're using?  And what your desired temperature sensing range is?

Comment: I am not using any thermocouple amplifier chip. I plan to use the output of the thermocouple for some PID loop control though.

Answer (score 2):

If the output of your signal conditioner is already 0-10V it does not need to be buffered and thus you can most likely use a simple voltage divider.

Recommended input impedance is <=1K so a 1K 0.1% resistor and 8.2K 0.1% resistor could be used. Any commercial signal conditioner should be able to drive a 9.2K resistance.

Unnecessarily adding op-amps can add errors (Vos, TCVos can be significant since an LSB is only 440uV) and could limit the range of the sensor signal that can be read (100mV minimum output voltage on a rail-to-rail op-amp translates to 555mV at the signal conditioner output).

Comment: I don't understand that last sentence about the 555mV

Comment: @ScottSeidman If the op-amp buffering the 1.8V signal can't get below 100mV at its output, then that corresponds to a 555mV (10/1.8 * 0.1) signal at the input to the divider  (output of the signal conditioner). He'd be losing the bottom 5.5% of the entire range.

Comment: aah, single sided op amp.

Comment: First of all thanks for the suggestion. By the way, can you please explain Vos, TCVos? I have no idea about them. And how do you arrive at 440 uV as the LSB?

Comment: Offset voltage (Vos) could be as much as several mV and will cause that much error in the output of a unity-gain buffer, and TCVos is how much that error changes with temperature. For the LSB- since it's a 12-bit converter, the LSB is 1.8/2^12 = 1.8/4096 = 439uV.

Comment: I thought we need to provide optocoupler to provide electrical isolation between the sensor output and BBB inputs. Don't you think it is required? When I designed the circuit for the digital sensors as inputs to BBB, I have used 4N35 optocoupler for the electrical isolation.

Comment: A decent thermocouple signal conditioner will have isolation built-in so that grounded thermocouples can be used with impunity. Precision analog signal/power isolation is non-trivial.

Comment: I am interested to know the analog input circuit of a PLC. Do they have a linear optocoupler to ensure isolation?

Comment: @Ritjeet You have to read the manual for the PLC and source, but I suspect there may be a common ground unless it's an input specifically designed for thermocouples, in which case it might be isolated or it might be a pseudo-differential arrangement (or if it's a crappy one, they may just tell you to use ungrounded junction T/Cs!).

Comment: Understood. But why do we prefer to provide electrical isolation only for digital inputs and not for analog outputs? Most of the circuit for connecting digital inputs to PLCs/MCUs generally consist of optocouplers e.g. 4N35. Where as, for analog inputs, as you have rightly mentioned, have only a common ground with the analog sensor.

Comment: Only one reason- because it costs MUCH more to do a proper job with precision analog isolation.

Comment: ha ha LOL :)  In any case, I am planning to do a proper job here. So I am planning to include a liner optocoupler like Vishay IL300 before the voltage divider circuit. Hoping for the best result. :)

Comment: You might want to look at some of the Avago chips- they're a lot less worse than the ancient IL300 and still relatively affordable compared to $100-class modules.

Comment: Ok, will try that :)

Answer (score 0):

If we get voltage output of 0 to 10 V from industrial signal conditioners of thermocouple, we can connect the output of that signal conditioners to voltage divider circuit of 8.2 K and 1 K. Then we can connect the output of voltage divider to HCNR200 linear opto coupler. To provide safety from reverse current, we can protect the circuit by providing a diode between the voltage divider and the HCNR200. The output of HCNR200 then goes to BeagleBone Black's analog input pin.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjZlgj.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>